# symfony jquery prototype dynamic form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, symfony

I am trying to realize a dynamic form with possibility to add\remove fields (just add for now cause it doesn't work). I am working with Symfony 2.0.13, and following the guide at [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype) 
but the result is that i can't obtain the

```
<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>
```

in the rendered html, as you can see [Here #2](http://pastebin.com/uQFw1Pf9)

Has anyone a clue?

Comment: can you show us your javascript ?

Comment: It's the same from the tutorial I posted,
http://pastebin.com/QkQSgqmZ

Comment: I am trying to figure out what's wrong but nothing

Comment: you can add the link directly to your view and just do the event on click on it that's what i did and it works like a charm !

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try it, but it doesn't satisfy me because it's not meant to do this way... Adding the link directly in my view doesn't scale for N fields am I right?

Comment: nop i'm using it to add as many field as i want. If you set the action add_tag() (or whatever) on the onclick of your button this will work for n times you click it (add one each time) there is no diference

Comment: Ah ok you use the same button to add N fields :), ok for the add, but for the delete it's not cause it needs a "delete button" for each field

Comment: that's true, did you try to just copy the code of the example in the symfony2's doc? did it work? Because i don't see why it's not working so you could just try to implement the code of the example and edit to make it your way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11358/discussion-between-linuxatico-and-coussinsky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change the script to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 // Get the div that holds the collection of tags
var collectionHolder = $('ul.tags');

// setup an "add a tag" link
var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_tag_link">Add a tag</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);


    // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
    collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

    $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
        // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
        e.preventDefault();

        // add a new tag form (see next code block)
        addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });
});
```

this will work...

Comment: need just to add the code var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addTagLink);
 inside the document.ready function

Comment: You won't believe it, but I solved this problem with exactly this solution just before you posted it.... :) anyway there were also other 2 problems related with Twig that I will post when I'll have more time. Thank you for your time